# Issue with DOJO Localization

Tags: localization, dojo

I am struggling for a long time with DOJO Localization.

My application folder structure is in following way.

[image]

And, the code to get localized strings is as follows.

```
 dojo.require("dojo.i18n");
    dojo.requireLocalization("CTop.recordings", "agent");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        //Returns a localized Object
        var localizedStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("CTop.recordings", "agent", "de");
```

I am getting empty **localizedStrings** object.

If i move recordings folder to the level of dojo folder (i.e. under Scripts), the following code is working fine.

```
 dojo.require("dojo.i18n");
    dojo.requireLocalization("recordings", "agent");
    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        //Returns a localized Object
        var localizedStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("recordings", "agent", "de");
```

What's the problem with adding CTop folder to structure? How to register the localization path?

I tried in following ways too but not succeeded.

```
dojo.require("dojo.i18n");
dojo.registerModulePath("myApp", "cTop.recordings.agent");
dojo.requireLocalization("myApp", "agent");
var localizedStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("myApp", "agent", "de");
```

Please guide me resolving this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937405/simple-dojo-i18n-implementation. It's using AMD...

Comment: problem: `dojo.registerModulePath("myApp", "cTop.recordings.agent");`, solution: see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i have two folders with the same name CTop. Renamed the folder which does not need localization. Following code snippet is enough to localize.

```
dojo.i18n.getLocalization("CTop.recordings", "agent", "de");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this (with the cTop directory folder intact, as in your screenshot)

```
// point the top-level namespace (such like 'dojo' is) to a folder by relative URI
// path here is a relative to dojo.js
dojo.registerModulePath("myApp", "../cTop/recordings"); 
dojo.requireLocalization("myApp", "agent");
var localizedStrings = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("myApp", "agent", "de");

// if you were to have a module declared in a file called 'myModule.js' under 'cTop' folder
// one could require it by following
dojo.require("myApp.myModule");
```

Comment: How's it hangin'? Have problems or you got em sorted?